# Google Access Token with multiple channels

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-api, youtube-api

I wonder how to distinguish a received access token for my different YouTube channels? I have a valid access token but the upload goes to the wrong channel. Can this be fixed somehow? Is there some kind of default channel?

Answer (score 0):

The permissions for upload or download depends on the ***scope*** parameter that is passed in the code when the authentication is made using the OAuth. You need to perform a check where the access token obtained has the same scope as that of the scope to upload a video.

In PHP the scope is set via

`$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');`

Check to see that this particular scope is present when you create an access token. Make use of the [OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) tool to test with the access token obtained by changing scopes.

Comment: The question seems to be about specifying which YouTube channel the upload will happen on, not the general permission of being able to upload videos.

Comment: In that case the uploader has to decide in which channel he/she wants to upload the video by specifying the Channel ID https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/working_with_channel_ids

Comment: So update your answer to say that and you'll have answered the question.

Comment: As @abraham pointed out, it is not about the scopes. The link you posted is about reading a channel ID. Am I able to set the id as well?